# Is it possible to change MapView Market pinColor programatically by clicking any button?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have implemented a MapView with react-native-maps. I'm trying to change Marker's pinColor by clicking on it.

Note: I have large amounts of markers. So I don't think refreshing all view can be a good solution. I need directly change the selected marker's color.

I didn't find how to do it. I tried below code:

```
class TestMap extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {

this.state = {
    testColor: "#FFFFFF",
    userLatitude:0,
    userLongitude:0,
    data:[]
}
}

render() {
return (
<MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        showsTraffic={true}
        showsBuildings={true}
        toolbarEnabled={true}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        style={styles.map}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: this.state.userLatitude,
          longitude: this.state.userLongitude,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
        }}
        onPoiClick={this.onPoiClick}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        followsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        loadingBackgroundColor="#FEA405"
        loadingIndicatorColor="white"
        onLongPress={e => this.onMapPress(e)}
        enableZoomControl
      >
        {this.ListMarkers()}
</MapView>
)};

ListMarkers() {
return this.state.data.map((data, i) => {
  return (
    <Marker
      key={i}
      onPress={e => this.onPressMarker(e, i, data)}
      coordinate={{
        longitude: data.LONGITUDE,
        latitude: data.LATITUDE
      }}
      pinColor={this.state.testColor}
    />
)}
)};

onPressMarker(e, index, data) {
   this.setState({testColor:"#000000"});
}
}
```

I expect the color of marker should change after clicking on it but it is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the selected pin in the state and use a different style in that case, if you have some id in your data you can use that value instead of the index:

```
    constructor(props) {
      this.state = {
        selectedPin: -1,
      }
    }

    ListMarkers = () => {
    return this.state.data.map((data, i) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          key={i}
          onPress={e => this.onPressMarker(e, i, data)}
          coordinate={{
            longitude: data.LONGITUDE,
            latitude: data.LATITUDE
          }}
          pinColor={ i === this.state.selectedPin ? '#FF0000' : '#FFFFFF'}
        />
    )}
    )};

    onPressMarker = (e, index, data)=> {
       this.setState({selectedPin:index});
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mariano, I tried your solution but it is not working.

Comment: I just realized that #000000 is not working. After I change it to red, its working now. Thanks.

Comment: Mariano did you test this on android or ios? It is working with ios but on android app crashed :( output----------->Trying to remove a view index above child count 0 view tag: 1455
 detail: View tag:1455
  children(0): [
 ],
  indicesToRemove(1): [
0,
 ],
  tagsToDelete(1): [
2453,
 ]